# Automating "Stay Awake"

Tags: automation

I use my personal Android smartphone for development. Every morning, I go to Settings \ Developer Options \ Stay Awake and check the box.

At the end of the day, I uncheck the box — since otherwise any notification (including the "fully charged" one) will trigger the screen on, and it will stay on from that point on.

How can these two operations be automated?